Numerical maximisation of a sum of functions over probability simplex
I'm trying to find the best approach to numerically maximise a sum
$$
F\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) =
\sum_{i}f_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)
$$
of $n$ continuous and piecewise-analytic functions
$f_{i}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, under the condition $\mbox{that}\ x$ lies on the probability simplex, namely, $\sum_{i}x_{i} = 1$ and $x_{i} \geq 0\,\,\, \forall\ i$. If it helps, we can assume the $f_i$ are increasing. I know little of numerical optimisation and tried to do some research, but came across a whole list of algorithms to do so, including those mentioned in the SciPy documentation on constrained optimisation: the Trust-Region Constrained Algorithm, SLSQP, COBYLA, etc$\ldots$
Question: I would like to know if there is any particular advantage in using one or the other in this particular simplex of optimisation over a probability simplex, with a decomposition into a sum of single-variable functions?  Alternatively, is there something more intelligent I can do than using a general-purpose constrained optimisation algorithm?

Perhaps try projecting the gradient onto the simplex?

Yes, that would be an option -- I also thought of the possibility of changing variables $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sigma(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ where $\sigma$ is the softmax function and $y_i$ are unconstrained, in order to remove the constraints from the optimization problem -- but I am guessing this can lead to other problems (vanishing gradients?). So my question is: what method is most appropriate here?

I would probably try doing a change of variables $x_n=1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$, and then introduce $\log$ barriers into the objective function to keep all the $x_i$ between 0 and 1. At each step you will need to check that you didn't cross a barrier, and backtrack part of the way if you do. Read up on interior point methods.

@Set Thanks for the suggestion! What is the advantage of this approach compared to the optimization algorithms I mentioned in the question?
